# Android architecture components and coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, kotlin-coroutines

There is a lot of information out there on architecture components, kotlin and coroutines but nowhere I can find an example using all those things together.
I'm struggling on how to use android's architecture components as described [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4snc6vPj6QIVmp3VCh1_dwohEAAYASAAEgLYGfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) together with coroutines. I have an idea but feel uncertain if it's the correct way of implementating this architectural style.
I'm trying to use the view model + repository pattern together with retro fit and coroutines.

I have the following repository:

```
class FooRepostiroy(private val fooHttpService: FooHttpService) {
   suspend fun someMethod() : SomeResult {
       val response = fooHttpService.someRemotCall() // which is also a suspending method using retrofit-2
       // process response, store it using room and return SomeResult data object
```

Then I use the FooRepository from my ViewModel but because someMethod is a suspending method I need to wrap it in a coroutine scope:

```
class FooViewModel(private val fooRepositoru : FooRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private var someMethodJob : Job? = null
    val result : MutableLiveData<SomeResult> = MutableLiveData()

    fun someMethod() {
        someMethodJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            result.value = fooRepositoru.someMethod()
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        someMethodJob?.cancel()
    }
```

Then in the fragment or activity I can observe the view model result

```
    fooViewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
```

Starting from my repository layer and below everything can be a suspending function. Then from the view model I can call any suspending function but never have a publicly exposed suspending function in my view model.
Is this the correct or proper way to incorporate coroutines with the view model architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct or proper way to incorporate coroutines with the view model architecture?

Yes!

Every instance of `ViewModel` has its own `ViewModelScope`.

The purpose of `ViewModelScope` is to run the jobs during the life cycle of that `ViewModel` and take care of automatic cancelation of running coroutine jobs in case the parent `Activity/Fragment` of `ViewModel` is destroyed.

Any running jobs under `ViewModelScope` will be canceled when the `ViewModel` will be destroyed.

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope)

Comment: So I don't need to keep a reference the kotlinx.coroutines.Job returned from the launch method and call job.cancel() in onCleared() manually ?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that manually, that is the whole purpose of existence of `ViewModelScope`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> private var someMethodJob : Job? = null
> val result : MutableLiveData<SomeResult> = MutableLiveData()
>
> fun someMethod() {
>     someMethodJob = viewModelScope.launch {
>         result.value = fooRepositoru.someMethod()
>     }
> }
> ```

You can ditch **all** of that and just say

```
val result: LiveData<SomeResult> = liveData {
    emit(fooRepository.someMethod())
}
```

And then observe `result`.